# Is the term "Borel transform" appropriate here?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sp.spectral-theory

Does anyone knows a reference for the name "Borel transform" given to the map $\mu\to F_\mu$ where $\mu$ is a probability measure on the real line and $F_\mu$ is the holomorphic function defined on the outside of the support of $\mu$ defined by the Cauchy integral

$$F_\mu(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d\mu(x)}{z-x}
$$

If the term "Borel transform" is incorrect what is the name for such a transformation?

Comment: I have often read the term "Stieltjes transform", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation

Comment: Thanks Mikael, it was my suggestion to the authors of an article, but I could not find the term before.

Comment: No, it is not appropriate. Borel transform is a version of Laplace transform. Its kernel is $\exp(zx)$.

Comment: Sometimes also called the Stieljes-Cauchy transform and there is also the Hilbert transform used most often among those doing signal processing. (The Laplace-Borel transform used in summing divergent series and in transforming e.g.f.s into o.g.f.s has strangely acquired the name Sumudu transform in recent decades among some researchers.)